# DataGrid WPF cant edit row An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, edit

Additional information: Element „EditItem” not allowed for this view

My class

```
public class MyData
{
    public int id { get;set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}
```

My list
    List ListaStrukt = new List();

xaml code

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">    
<Grid GotFocus="Grid_GotFocus">          
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="184*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="135*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Name="ButtonEdit" Visibility="Hidden" Margin="274,32,0,105">Edit selected cell</Button>
    <Button Name="NextRow" Margin="210,32,243,110" Click="NextRow_Click" Visibility="Hidden" >Previous</Button>
    <Button Margin="0,32,396,110" Click="Button_Click" Visibility="Hidden">Find</Button>
    <Label Name="Labeliffound" Margin="10,37,0,110" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="210"/>
    <TextBox Name="TextBoxName"  Margin="274,0,121,152" GotFocus="TextBoxName_GotFocus">Type here Name</TextBox>
    <TextBox Name="TextBoxLastName" Margin="396,0,0,152" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="121" GotFocus="TextBoxTitle_GotFocus" >Type here last name</TextBox>
    <Button Name="ButtonName" Margin="274,32,0,105" Click="ButtonName_Click">Add name and Last name</Button>
    <TextBox Name="TexBoxSearch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" GotFocus="TexBoxSearch_GotFocus" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" Margin="1,0,248,152" >Type here to search</TextBox>
    <DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" DataGridCell.Selected="myDataGrid_GotFocus" ItemsSource="{Binding ListaStrukt}" CanUserAddRows="True" IsReadOnly="False" CanUserReorderColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="True"  Margin="0,79,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" KeyDown="myDataGrid_KeyDown_1" SelectionChanged="myDataGrid_SelectionChanged" LostFocus="myDataGrid_LostFocus" GotFocus="myDataGrid_GotFocus" Cursor="None">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header=" Id" Width="30" Binding="{Binding id}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="60" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Width="90" Binding="{Binding LastName, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Errors

> Cannot obtain value of local or argument '' as it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away.    System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection
>
> Cannot obtain value of local or argument 'item' as it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away.  object

I was trying to resolve this but i read so many posts and answers and still nothing.

Error shows up when I want to double click on DataGrid cell. I would be grateful for help.

Comment: why wuld be trying to edit, if you have ", Mode=OneWay"

Comment: I'm sorry i forgot to delete that, This error was annoying so i set one way mode temporary.